# Creating several profile classes in django

Tags: python, django, profile

I'm getting started with django and I'd like to extend the basic `django.contrib.auth.models.User` class to create my own site profile(s). [Here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users) is described how to do it, got that.

As far as I've understood it, you can only specify a single class as `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE` in your `settings.py`.

Now, if I create an extension class of my profile class like this

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    somefield = models.CharField()

class UserProfileExtended(UserProfile):
    extrafield = models.CharField()
```

then I cannot make both of them profile classes, right?

(I know, in this case you'd just add the `extrafield` to the superclass and drop the `UserProfileExtended` entirely. Just imagine you have so many fields in `UserProfileExtended` that you really want to split them up)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/678496/whats-the-best-way-to-have-different-profiles-for-different-kinds-of-users-in-dj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be only one profile class.  I guess I don't understand the scenario where you would want to split them up.  In any case,

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = "UserProfileExtended"
```

should handle the inheritance correctly for the simple example you give.